# Read Word document paragraph by paragraph using DocumentFormat.OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I am trying to read word document paragraph using DocumentFormat.OpenXML library and printing the result on a label.

Below is my code :

```
 {
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"D:\Files\File3.docx", true))
        {
            var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            var paras = body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph>();
            //string prg = body.InnerText;
            //Label1.Text = prg.ToString();
            foreach (var para in paras)
            {
                Label1.Text = para.ToString();
                foreach (var run in para.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text>())
                    {
                        Response.Write(text);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Commented part is working fine.
i have two keywords to search and paragraphs between those two keywords should print on label.

Comment: Saying it is "not working" isn't helpful.  What do you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: does it look okay now?